# How to set value in the textbox from database that contain a quotation mark in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel and I have an update modal. My data is not set on the modal because one of the data contain quotation mark like in the picture below.
[image]

My button's code is like this:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartitem_update_modal" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-warning btn-circle" onclick="cartitem_update_modal('{{ $getdata->EQC_ID }}'
                                       , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_ID }}'
                                       , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_NAME }}'
                                       , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_QUANTITY }}'
                                       , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_UNIT }}'
                                       , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_REMARK }}')">
                                      <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </a>
```

and my javascript code is like this:

```
function cartitem_update_modal(EQC_ID, EQC_ITEM_ID, EQC_ITEM_NAME, EQC_ITEM_QUANTITY, EQC_ITEM_UNIT, EQC_ITEM_REMARK) 
{
    $('#cart_item_id_update').val(EQC_ID);
    $('#cart_item_update').val(EQC_ITEM_NAME);
    $('#cart_item_reserved_quantity_update').val(EQC_ITEM_QUANTITY);
    $('#cart_item_reserved_unit_update').val(EQC_ITEM_UNIT);
    $('#cart_item_remark_update').val(EQC_ITEM_REMARK);
}
```

And my problem is the Item Name not appear on my textbox `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cart_item_update" readonly>` and it is because the data has quotation mark. I tried select the data which not contain quotation mark, and it's worked well, the data showed up in the text box.

Comment: You need to HTML encode the quotes in the values you concatenate in to the attribute, so `"` needs to be `&quot;`

Comment: Try  `{{ htmlentities($getdata->EQC_ITEM_NAME) }}`

Comment: can you pop() and shift() the quotation mark and use it.. just a work around or encode the html part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that you will be using it inside a javascript call, just replace the `'` by `\'` or replace it with (space) or nothing

```html
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartitem_update_modal" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-warning btn-circle" onclick="cartitem_update_modal('{{ $getdata->EQC_ID }}'
    , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_ID }}'
    , '{{ str_replace("'", "\'", $getdata->EQC_ITEM_NAME) }}'
    , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_QUANTITY }}'
    , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_UNIT }}'
    , '{{ str_replace("'", "\'", $getdata->EQC_ITEM_REMARK) }}')">
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: It worked. but it changed (') into (/). So I use `str_replace("'", "\'", $getdata->EQC_ITEM_NAME)`

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartitem_update_modal" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-warning btn-circle" 
   onclick="cartitem_update_modal('{{ $getdata->EQC_ID }}'
            , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_ID }}'
            , '{{ htmlentities($getdata->EQC_ITEM_NAME) }}'
            , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_QUANTITY }}'
            , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_UNIT }}'
            , '{{ $getdata->EQC_ITEM_REMARK }}')"> 
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cart_item_update').val(EQC_ITEM_NAME.replace(/\YOURQUOTATION_MARK/g, ''));
```

To remove all instances of £, € and $ for example you use

```
EQC_ITEM_NAME.replace(/£|\$|€|,|\./g, '')
```